# Is having multiple lambdas chain calls a bad idea?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

We are currently using serverless framework for our microservices, currently each services is stored in a single big lambda that handle many types of requests.

It seems that the standard is to have a lambda per request type, so each of our servers would end up being broken up in many pieces.

I am afraid that if I have to call other of these new functions I would end up chaining invocations (and thus paying for a lot of lambdas that are waiting).

How do you tackle this?

Comment: You certainly do not want to have one Lambda function call a second Lambda function synchronously because in that case you would be paying double, for the overlapping time. I'm not sure what you mean when you say "a lambda per request type" (what is a request type in your application?) but here's some advice from serverless on architectural patterns: https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-architecture-code-patterns/

Answer (score 0):

You could have one lambda trigger another asynchronously. Then you can have small, quick functions.  Here is some sample Python code for this:

```
payload = {'any-data-you-need-to-pass-along': 'your_data',
           'resources': ['you_can_make_this_something_custom']}

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName=the_arn_of_function_you_want_to_call,
                     InvocationType='Event', 
                     Payload=json.dumps(payload))
```

The key is to use the InvocationType of "Event" as that causes the call to be asynchronous.  One advantage of this approach is that each different type of request can have a lambda that is tailored to its needs in terms of memory and timeout.  If everything runs in one big lambda--like a big switch statement--then your lambda must be configured to the highest memory any of the request types requires, and that may mean small request types run with more than they need and waste your money.

I recommend you read up on the asynchronous notes [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) that talks about other considerations:

> For asynchronous invocation, Lambda adds events to a queue before
>   sending them to your function. If your function does not have enough
>   capacity to keep up with the queue, events may be lost. Occasionally,
>   your function may receive the same event multiple times, even if no
>   error occurs. To retain events that were not processed, configure your
>   function with a dead-letter queue.

If you need more of a flow, you should look into Step Functions: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-lambda/